# Django: Prepare multiple SQL condition with where

Tags: python, sql, django

I have POST data:

```
filter[param1][type]:text
filter[param1][range]:null
filter[param1][suffix]:
filter[param1][prefix]:
filter[param1][v][text]:33
filter[param1][v][type]:has
filter[param2][type]:text
filter[param2][range]:null
filter[param2][suffix]:
filter[param2][prefix]:
filter[param2][v][text]:make
filter[param2][v][type]:has
...
```

This is handler for POST request in my view:
    filter = (request.POST.get('filter', False))

```
if (filter is not False):
    filter_obj = json.loads(filter)
    for key, value in filter_obj.items():
        if value.get('v') is not None:
            filters[key] = value.get('v').get('text')
```

Need to get prepared multiple SQL condition with where:

```
WHERE (
    param1 = 33 AND 
    param2 = make AND
    ...
)
```

How I can do it in Django?

Comment: Did you even check online how to write Django where clause? There are plenty out there :) What did you try?

Comment: Yes. I find condition like: conditions['table_name'] = 'Q( row_name = param_text )' but I can't use it with dynamically data

Comment: By dynamic you mean, your data is coming from a post http request? Is your dynamic data in `filter[param1]` and `filter[param2]`? Could you give more details about your data?

Comment: I want to get raw text solution, because I planned to use alias_name to tables.

Comment: So you are interested in using `Raw SQL query` and not Django Query searcher?

Comment: LearningNeverStops: yes

Comment: Then I suggest you to look into: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 0):

ugly things happen like this!
......... imagen situation like Ur... U know ugly conditions

```
if len(request.POST.get("name"))>1:
    Object.objects.filter(name =request.POST.get("name"))
if len(request.POST.get("name"))>1 and len(request.POST.get("id"))>1:
    Object.objects.filter(name =request.POST.get("name"), id = request.POST.get("id"))
```

shortcut or answer:

```
kwargs = {}
if len(request.POST.get("name"))>1:
    kwargs['name']=request.POST.get("name")
if len(request.POST.get("id"))>1:
    kwargs['id']=request.POST.get("id")
result = Object.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

but answer is too late. sorry